# EXCEL VBA taking material from a word doc

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am using an Excel macro to extract text from a Word doc and store it.

Everything works fine except for one irritating fault. While the routine is running I want to be looking at the worksheet rather than the document from which the data is being extracted. I cannot find how to do this. The relevant bit of code is :

```
Sub Break_down()
'
' This macro will take a whole series of word documents in the same (or different)
' folder(s) and will find the number of words and then grab some text
'
' I have previously added from Tools > References MS Word 12.0 Object Library
'
Dim sorsfilename(1 To 50) As String
'
Dim m As Integer, n As Integer, np As Long, nw As Integer
Dim npara As Integer, para_count As Integer
'
Dim objWKB As Excel.Workbook
Dim a As Object
'
Dim objWord As Object
Dim oRng As Word.Range
'
Dim objDoc
Dim rngParagraphs As Range
'
Dim wkb1 As Workbook
'
Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
'objWord.Visible = False  ' This did not work
'
Set wkb1 = ActiveWorkbook
sj = ActiveSheet.Name
Set a = wkb1.Worksheets("Sheet2")
'
sorsfilename(10) = "E:\Mining Expts\Sorse10.docx"
'plus other file names  "
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a break point to pause the macro execution, when it hits, arrange the windows on the screen the way you wish to see them, then remove the breakpoint and press F5 to continue execution.

Comment: Neither F5 nor F8 wold re-start from the break point. I'm wondering about my KB now as I rarely use the F keys.

Comment: The menu equivalent is Run / Continue. BTW, I can't think of any reason why you would ever want to create an instance of Excel.Application within an Excel application.

Answer (score 0):

This approach works for me:

```
Sub GetWordData()
'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model.
'See under the VBE's Tools|References.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document, wdRng As Word.Range
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, ArrList()
Dim WkSht As Worksheet, i As Long, r As Long
ArrList() = Array("E:\Mining Expts\Sorse1.docx", "E:\Mining Expts\Sorse2.docx", "E:\Mining Expts\Sorse3.docx", _
    "E:\Mining Expts\Sorse4.docx", "E:\Mining Expts\Sorse5.docx", "E:\Mining Expts\Sorse6.docx", _
    "E:\Mining Expts\Sorse7.docx", "E:\Mining Expts\Sorse8.docx", "E:\Mining Expts\Sorse9.docx", _
    "E:\Mining Expts\Sorse10.docx", "E:\Mining Expts\Sorse11.docx", "E:\Mining Expts\Sorse12.docx")
Set WkSht = ActiveSheet
r = WkSht.Cells(WkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application
With wdApp
  'Hide the Word session
  .Visible = False
  'Disable any auto macros in the documents being processed
  .WordBasic.DisableAutoMacros
  'Disable any alerts in the documents being processed
  .DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
  For i = 0 To UBound(ArrList)
    strFile = ArrList(i): r = r + 1
    Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(Filename:=strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    With wdDoc
      'Get the document word count
      WkSht.Cells(r, 1) = .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
      'Get the other document data, for example
      WkSht.Cells(r, 2) = .Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
      .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
  Next
  .Quit
End With
Set wdRng = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set WkSht = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```